# How to add action to `Button`?

Tags: python, pygame

I added classes 'Button' to they do action in my game, but I don't khow how to realize them. What should I do to my program will work correctly without errors?

```
class Button2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        #[...]
    def draw(self, x, y, message, action = None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if x < mouse[0] < x + self.width and y < mouse[1] < y + self.height:
             pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.active_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))
             if click[0] == 1:
                 if action is not None:
                     action()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.inactive_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))
        print_text_5(message, x + 10, y + 10)
def game():
    Game = True
    while Game:
        clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                player.jump()
            elif event.key == K_p:
                pause()
            elif event_key == K_k:
                Game = False
Begining = True
while Begining:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Begining = False
    mini_button = Button2(180, 120)
    screen.blit(important_phone_jpg, important_phone_rect)
    print_text_5('Welcome to my game!', 300, 50)
    mini_button.draw(570, 200, 'PLAY')
    mini_button.draw(570, 420, 'QUIT')
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Yes I can see the function `game`. However you have to passe `game` to an `Button` instance. e.g.: `mini_button.draw(570, 200, 'PLAY', game)`

Comment: After invoking `action`, the loop in the `game` function is running. You have to implement a complete application loop inside the `game` function (event handling, display update, ...)

Comment: Of course I've seen the wrong indentation. I thought it was just due to the poor formatting of your question. Anyway this is a typographical mistake. Therefore the question should be deleted. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make spaces after clock.tick(FPS)

```
    Game = True
    while Game:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:    
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    player.jump()
                elif event.key == K_p:
                    pause()
                elif event_key == K_k:
                    Game = False
```

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.